# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing

i have this simple line of code :

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Mon 7:00 PM", "ddd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you run this code, 6 days in a week,it will throw this exception :

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.
```

If you run it on Monday, it will run OK. Is there any way to parse that string correctly ?

Comment: No, because if you ommit any parts of the date it defaults to "todays date", which for 6 days out of 7 every week will not be a Monday. ParseExact is not a "find a matching date" type of thing, it only parses the string, for instance if you use `ParseExact("30.03", "dd.MM", culture)`, it will work but if you specify `"Tue 30.03", "ddd dd.MM"`, it will not try to figure out which year is going to have 30th of March on a Tuesday, and neither is it going to try to figure out which monday you're talking about. You're going to need to find a different way.

Comment: i see, so the DateTime just fills in missing info (unknown date -> todays date) and that creates conflict. Can you post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, DateTime.Parse(Exact) will always return a complete DateTime, complete with a date.

If you ommit any parts detailing the date, it will default to todays date. 6 out of 7 days each week, that will not match the pattern that states monday, and that's why you get that exception.

ParseExact will not attempt to find a matching DateTime value.

For instance, if you run this:

```
ParseExact("Mon 30.03", "ddd dd.MM", culture)
```

it will work this year, because 30th of March 2020 is a Monday. However, in 2021, 30th of a March will be on a Tuesday, and thus it will fail again. ParseExact will not try to find a matching year that would have 30th of March on a Monday, and it's the same thing with just specifying Monday. It will not try to figure out which Monday you're talking about.

In short, you will need to find a different way of doing this.

I guess you should step back from ParseExact, and ask yourself, how **exactly** should "Mon 30.03" be translated into a specific date in a specific year. What is the logic. Then you can try to find the right method to call, or most likely, write the code to do it.